# How to average elements in several data frames with unequal size?

Tags: r, dataframe, average, reduce

I have a series of text files (100 files) with same structure (same number of columns) that need to be averaged for each element in all files. What I use is this code:

```
my.list<-list()
for(j in 1:100){
  my.list[[j]]<-read.table(paste('file_',j,'.txt',sep='')
                               ,header=TRUE)
}

all=Reduce("+", my.list) / length(my.list)
```

This works quit fine when all the data frames have the same size. But when I have more rows in several data frames I get this error:

> Error in Ops.data.frame(init, x[[i]]) :    ‘+’ only defined for
>   equally-sized data frames

I would like to know if there is any solution to make the average of existing number for the rows that are not presented in all the data frames.

Here is example files with 1 column (I just put two files but in my data is 100 files):

file1:

```
             x
1 3
2 5
3 1
4 8
5 2
6 6
7 0
```

file2:

```
           x
1 4
2 2
3 6
4 1
5 9
6 2
```

and I want an output:

```
          x
1 3.5
2 3.5
3 3.5
4 4.5
5 5.5
6 4
7 0
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try the updated code?

Comment: Yes I'm trying :) I will keep you updtaed

Comment: @mahmood: do you want to average by the total number of columns that are present in your whole dataset (in this ex. 2) or by the number of data that are in a particular row? (for row 7 this is 1) ? This may make your results different.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart by the number of data that are in a particular row.

Comment: @mahmood: Just for the records, the zoo package provides an alternative option for this (see below in the answer)

Comment: My first instinct was simply pad with NAs, then just do `mean(..., na.rm=T)` as @RuthgerRighart has posted. NA is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to "rbind" the list elements (`list(x,y)`).  The `id.col=TRUE` generates the `id` for each list elements.  Create a sequence index (`.idx`) grouped by ".id", use the ".idx" as grouping variable and get the means of subset of datatable (`.SD`) by using `lapply`.  The `.SDcols` specifies the columns to select for "mean" calculation.

```
library(data.table) # data.table_1.9.5 
rbindlist(list(x,y), idcol=TRUE)[,.idx:=1:.N , by = .id][, 
                  lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=2:3, by= .idx]
#    .idx Col1 Col2
#1:    1    1  3.5
#2:    2    2  3.5
#3:    3    3  3.5
#4:    4    4  4.5
#5:    5    5  5.5
#6:    6    6  4.0
#7:    7    7  0.0
```

Or we could use another option suggested by @David Arenburg.  The steps are the same as above except using `colMeans` instead of `lapply(.SD,`.

```
rbindlist(list(x,y), idcol=TRUE)[, .idx:=1:.N, by =.id][,
              as.list(colMeans(.SD)), .SDcols=2:3, by = .idx]
```

#### Update

Suppose if the datasets have variable `ncols` from multiple datasets, we could read all the files from the working directory using `fread`, use `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE`, and use the code as above with appropriate changes in the `.SDcols`

```
  files <- list.files() 
  lst <- lapply(files, fread)
  rbindlist(lst, idcol=TRUE, fill=TRUE)[, .idx:=1:.N, by =.id][,
              as.list(colMeans(.SD, na.rm=TRUE)), .SDcols=2:3, by = .idx]
```

Using an example

```
  lst <- list(x,y,z)
  rbindlist(lst, idcol=TRUE, fill=TRUE)[, 
     .idx:=1:.N, by=.id][, as.list(colMeans(.SD, na.rm=TRUE)),
               .SDcols=2:4, by=.idx][,-1, with=FALSE]
  #    Col1     Col2 Col3
  #1:    1 3.000000    3
  #2:    2 3.333333    4
  #3:    3 3.666667    5
  #4:    4 4.666667    6
  #5:    5 5.666667    7
  #6:    6 4.000000  NaN
  #7:    7 0.000000  NaN
```

#### Update2

A `base R` option would be to create a list ("lst1") with list elements have equal dimensions.  This can be done by first creating a `NA` dataset "d1" with dimensions equal to "maximum" nrow/ncol from checking the dimensions of "lst" (`Dim1 <- sapply(..)`).  Use `Map` to fill the elements of "d1" that match with the "rownames/colnames" of each "lst" element.  The output "lst1" can be converted to array (`ar1`), use `apply` with margins (`c(1,2)`) to get the `mean` value.

```
   Dim1 <- sapply(lst, dim)
   d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=max(Dim1[2,]), 
                              nrow=max(Dim1[1,])))
   nm1 <- unique(unlist(sapply(lst, colnames)))
   names(d1) <- nm1
   lst1 <-Map(function(x,y) {
      y[match(row.names(x), row.names(y)),
                  match(colnames(x), colnames(y))] <- x
       y }, 
       lst, list(d1))

 ar1 <- array(unlist(lst1), dim=c(max(Dim1[1,]), max(Dim1[2,]), length(lst1)))
 apply(ar1, c(1,2), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
 #      [,1]     [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    1 3.000000    3
 #[2,]    2 3.333333    4
 #[3,]    3 3.666667    5
 #[4,]    4 4.666667    6
 #[5,]    5 5.666667    7
 #[6,]    6 4.000000  NaN
 #[7,]    7 0.000000  NaN
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(Col1 = 1:7, Col2 = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 0L
)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -7L))

y <- structure(list(Col1 = 1:6, Col2 = c(4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 2L)), 
.Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

z <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=2:6, Col3=3:7)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `as.list(colMeans(.SD))` instead of `lapply(.SD, mean)` as it is vectorized

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I think it is a better replacement.  I will try with some benchmarks just out of curiosity

Comment: columns Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that I have over 100 data frames. And in some cases they have more than 1 column. Thats why I used 'reduce'. I just put an example with 1 column for simplicity.

Comment: @mahmood You have to show an example that mimics your original dataset.  When you show two datasets with n columns, I would think it should be the case for original dataset and the only difference is in the `nrows`.  Having said that, You can use `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` to fill the unequal columns with NAs

Comment: @mahmood Also, if there are hundred datasets, it is better to directly read it using `fread` with `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.
I tried several time! I have the files read-in in the `lst`. The columns names are `V1` and `V2`. When I apply the `rebindlist` command. I get this error:
`Error in rbindlist(lst, idcol = TRUE, fill = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (idcol = TRUE)`
I think its because I have no idcol (like your example Col1,...) and I couldn't figure our how to define one! Thanks again in advance

Comment: @mahmood I am using `data.table_1.9.5`, but i think `data.table_1.9.4` would still work.  Which version do you have?  I also don't have any `idcol`, it will be generated by using `idcol=TRUE`

Comment: @akrun I use data.table_1.9.4.

Comment: @mahmood I am using devel version, the `idcol` is a recent entry.  You could install the devel version from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table if 1.9.4 doesn't work.  BTW, I updated with a base R solution as well.

Comment: Thanks again. For all the updates and helps. Finally I uses the base R solution.

Comment: @mahmood Glad to know that it was helpful.  I tried a `Reduce` solution, but it is not that worthy when the column/rows are not similar and also when there are NA values

Answer (score 3):

The following solution uses the zoo package

```
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)
```

**Two unequal vectors**

```
file1<-c(3,5,1,8,2,6,0)
file2<-c(4,2,6,1,9,2)

z1<-zoo(file1)
z2<-zoo(file2)

dat<-cbind(z1,z2)

rowMeans(dat, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**For more than 2 vectors:**

```
file3<-c(2,3)
z3<-zoo(file3)
dat<-cbind(z1,z2,z3)

rowMeans(dat, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Unequal matrices**

```
z1<-zoo(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(0,2,7)))
z2<-zoo(cbind(c(0,3,4,7,2),c(1,4,2,3,8)))

dat<-cbind(z1,z2)
rowMeans(dat, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Note:** in the provided examples the missing elements are filled up with NA's. If you use cbind(z1,z2,fill=0) the NA's are filled up with zero values which produces different row mean values.

Comment: Of course. Pad with NAs, then just do `mean(..., na.rm=T)`